# Subscribing to realtime updates for an app that is marked as "native'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time, native, facebook-oauth

When I follow the instructions on:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Namely:
1) Retrive an access_token with:
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials`

2) Issue a subscription request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions?access_token=...`

I receive the error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#15) This method is not supported for native apps","type":"OAuthException","code":15}}
```

My app is marked as a native app under "App Type" on `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app id>/advanced`.
But, to be clear, I am making the subscription request from a **server** (the same server that I intend to use as my callback server).

**So, questions:**

1. Should I be getting an access_token via some other means?  Does
   the way I'm getting the access token
   ("`grant_type=client_credentials`") mean that I'm getting an access token that is supposed to be for a client, rather than a server?
2. Am I doing something else wrong?  Or,
   is this just a bug / documentation bug?  Nowhere in the realtime API
   docs does it say that Native apps are not alllowed to use the realtime API.

**Related questions:**

[How do I subscribe to Facebook Realtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800452/how-do-i-subscribe-to-facebook-realtime-api) is basically my same question, but it's not on facebook.stackoverflow.com and it was answered with a non-answer, so I saw fit to repost.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11141333/using-real-time-updates-from-facebook-graph-api-with-a-client-application is a related question, but again, I am making a subscription request from a *SERVER*, not a client.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a canvas_url, you can do client_credentials. So setup native AND canvas (server). It will host a web site version of your app, which is what FB needs to grant that kind of access_token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  We already have "Website with Facebook Login" and "Mobile Web" enabled.  Are you saying that I need to enable "App on Facebook" and add a canvas_url in order to be able to use client_credentials?  If so, do you have any idea **why** that is the case?

Comment: Yes. Because you need to have a web server, that is the party that calls the client credentials. Can't currently do that from a mobile (and that doesn't really make sense, the way I understand it.)

Comment: Right, I wasn't trying to do it from mobile.  In any case, here's what finally worked: setting "App Type" to "Web" on `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<appid>/advanced`, subscribing to Real-Time Updates, and then setting "App Type" back to "Native/Desktop."  Even after switching "App Type" back to "Native/Desktop," the Real-Time updates are still flowing in.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to find and answer this question! :)

Comment: Oh interesting, so I guess by setting and unsetting that in Facebook dev, basically you must have initialized the Real Time updates.